# where is the call to encode the string or force the string to need to be encoded in this file?

Tags: python, string, encoding, file-io, pyqt

I know this may seem rude or mean or unpolite, but I need some help to try to figure out why I cant call `window.loadPvmFile("f:\games@DD.ATC3.Root\common\models\a300\amu\dummy.pvm")` exactly like that as a string. Instead of doing that, it gives me a traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "F:\Python Apps\pvmViewer_v1_1.py", line 415, in <module>
        window.loadPvmFile("f:\games\@DD.ATC3.Root\common\models\a300\amu\dummy.pvm")
    File "F:\Python Apps\pvmViewer_v1_1.py", line 392, in loadPvmFile
        file1 = open(path, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:
'f:\\games\\@DD.ATC3.Root\\common\\models\x07300\x07mu\\dummy.pvm'
```

Also notice, that in the traceback error, the file path is different. When I try a path that has no letters in it except for the drive letter and filename, it throws this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Python Apps\pvmViewer_v1_1.py", line 416, in <module>
    loadPvmFile('f:\0\0\dummy.pvm')
File "F:\Python Apps\pvmViewer_v1_1.py", line 393, in loadPvmFile
    file1 = open(path, "r")
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

I have searched for the place that the encode function is called or where the argument is encoded and cant find it. Flat out, I am out of ideas, frustrated and I have nowhere else to go. The source code can be found here: [PVM VIEWER](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2660)

Also note that you will not be able to run this code and load a pvm file and that I am using portable python 2.7.3! Thanks for everyone's time and effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\a` and `\0` are escape sequences. Use `r''` (or `R''`) around the string to mark it as a [raw string](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

`window.loadPvmFile(r"f:\games@DD.ATC3.Root\common\models\a300\amu\dummy.pvm")`

Comment: then it throws an attribute error: PvmViewer() has no attribute pat

Comment: This means the file is being loaded; so open another question with the exception you are getting along with your source and the trackback.

Comment: AHA! I found part of it: the function that needs to be called is the itemActivated, but it requires a QTreeWidgetItem argument